# Compare neighbouring cells in a 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, multidimensional-array

Suppose this is a 3X3 matrix and I need to find the number of elements that are greater than their neighbours.

```
[[1 2 7], 
[4 5 6],
[3 8 9]]
```

Neighbours are those cells whose corners touch each other.

```
1 has neighbours 2,4,5.
2 has neighbours 1,7,4,5,6.
7 has 2,5,6.
5 has 1,2,7,4,6,3,8,9 and so on.
```

Comment: Whats the expected output?

Comment: @U12-Forward expected output is 2. 7 and 9 being the elements that are greater than their neighbours.

Comment: @Anonymousss please review the proposed solution below. Let me know if there's any questions.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in two steps/functions: 1) `get_neighbors`(matrix, r, c), and 2) `compare_neighbors`(matrix). In the 2nd function, `compare_neighbors` we just call get_neighbors and passing all coordinates by leveraging `itertools.product`.

```
# code snippet:
from itertools import product

def get_neighbors(matrix, r, c):
    sum((row[c -(c>0): c+2]
         for row in matrix[r -(r>0):r+2]), [])  # sum() beats itertools.chain()

    vals.remove(grid[r][c])     # rm itself.

    return set(vals)            # keep distinct nums. ONLY

def compare_neighbors(matrix):
    ROW, COL = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    result = []

    for x, y in product(range(ROW), range(COL)):
        current = matrix[x][y]
        all_nums = get_neighbors(matrix, x, y) 

        if all(x < current for x in all_nums): 
           result.append(current)
    return result
```

Program running:

```
grid = [[1, 5, 4, 9], 
        [2, 6, 3, 2], 
        [8, 3, 6, 3], 
        [5, 4, 7, 1]]

matrix = [[1, 2, 7], 
          [4, 5, 6], 
          [3, 8, 9]] 

print(f' {compare_neighbors(matrix)} ')     # [7, 9]
print(f' {compare_neighbors(grid) } ')      # [9, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tackle different problems:

- ensure you got data that fits the problemstatement - a matrix of strings f.e. does not work nor does a non-quadratic data input
- get the actual neighbouring indexes based on a potential neighbourhood
- check all neighbours for bigger then testing-index

You can get the dimensions directly from the provided data (after assertioning it conforms to some base rules) and provide a generic check based on this like so:

```
# different neighbourhood tuples
neigh8 = tuple((a,b) for a in range(-1,2) for b in range(-1,2))
neigh4 = tuple((a,b) for (a,b) in neigh8 if a or b)

def assertions(data):
    """Check if data is list of lists and all dims are same.
    Check if all elements are either ints or floats.
    Exit with exception if not."""
    assert isinstance(data, list)
    outer_dim = len(data)
    for inner in data:
        assert outer_dim == len(inner), f"Inner element not of len {outer_dim}: {inner}"
        assert isinstance(inner, list), f"Inner element not list: {inner}"
        allNumbers = all(isinstance(i, (int, float)) for i in inner)
        assert allNumbers, f"Not all elements ints or floats: {inner}"

    return outer_dim


def test_surrounded_by_lower_numbers(data, idx, n_idx):
    """Test one element at 'idx' in 'data' for a given neighbourhood 'n_idx'
    and return True if surrounded only by smaller numbers."""

    def get_idx(data, idx, n_idx):
        """Get all indexes that conform to the given neighbourhood and are
        not identical to idx nor out of bounds."""
        n = []
        for (a,b) in n_idx:
            # identical to input idx
            if (idx[0]+a , idx[1]+b) == idx:
                continue
            # out of bounds
            if idx[0]+a < 0 or idx[1]+b < 0: 
                continue
            if idx[0]+a >= len(data) or idx[1]+b >= len(data): 
                continue
            n.append( (idx[0]+a , idx[1]+b ))
        return n

    value =  data[idx[0]][idx[1]]

    n = get_idx(data, idx, n_idx)

    # check if all are smaller as the current value
    return all (data[a][b] < value for a,b in n)

def test_matrix(matrix, n_idx = neigh8):
    """Check all matrix values for given neighbourhood. Output alle values that are
    surrounded only by strictly smaller values."""
    print()
    for i in matrix:
        for n in i:
            print(f"{float(n):>5.2f} ".replace(".00","   "), end=" ")
        print()
    print()
    dim = assertions(matrix)
    for (a,b) in ((a,b) for a in range(dim) for b in range(dim)):
        if test_surrounded_by_lower_numbers(matrix,(a,b)):
            print(f"{(a,b)} = {matrix[a][b]} is biggest.")
```

Program:

```
# 3 x 3
test_matrix( [[1, 2, 7], [4, 5, 6], [3, 8, 9]] )

# 5 x 5
test_matrix([[1, 2, 7, 11, 9], 
             [4, 5, 6, -2, .5], 
             [9.1, 3,99.99, 8, 9.7], 
             [1,2,3,4,5], 
             [40,50,60,70,80]])
```

Output for 3x3 testcase:

```
 1      2      7     
 4      5      6     
 3      8      9     

(0, 2) = 7 is biggest.
(2, 2) = 9 is biggest.
```

Output for 5x5 testcase:

```
 1      2      7     11      9     
 4      5      6     -2      0.50  
 9.10   3     99.99   8      9.70  
 1      2      3      4      5     
40     50     60     70     80     

(0, 3) = 11 is biggest.
(2, 0) = 9.1 is biggest.
(2, 2) = 99.99 is biggest.
(2, 4) = 9.7 is biggest.
(4, 4) = 80 is biggest.
```